# Stored and clear array location

Tags: java, android, arrays, checkbox

I am using check box using stored value in the array location when select and deselect the check box means to be clear the particular array index value and store the another check box value at the same location.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int m[] =new int[5];
int count=1;
int t=0;
CheckBox chk1,chk2,chk3,chk4;
int flag,increment=0;
int b;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    chk1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    chk2=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    chk3=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
    chk4=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
    Button next=(Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
    Button previous=(Button)findViewById(R.id.previous);      
    chk1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(chk1.isChecked())
            {                                       
                flag=1;
                m[increment]=flag;
                increment++;
                count++;                
            }
            else 
            { increment--;
            count--;        

            }               
        }
    });
    chk2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(chk2.isChecked())
            {
                flag=2;
                m[increment]=flag;
                increment++;
                count++;
            }
            else        
            {                   
                increment--;
                count--;
            }               
        }
    });
    chk3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(chk3.isChecked())
            {
                flag=3;
                m[increment]=flag;
                increment++;
                count++;
            }
            else 
            {       
                increment--;
                count--;
            }
        }
    });
    chk4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(chk1.isChecked())
            {
                flag=4;
                m[increment]=flag;
                increment++;
                count++;        
            }
            else
            {   
                increment--;
                count--;
            }
        }});
    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            t++;
            if(t<4)
            {
                switch (t) {
                case 1:
                    b=m[0];
                    if(b==1)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "one", 100).show();
                    }else if(b==2)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "two", 100).show();
                    }else if(b==3)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "three", 100).show();
                    }else if(b==4)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "four", 100).show();
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    b=m[1];
                    if(b==1)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "one", 100).show();
                    }else if(b==2)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "two", 100).show();
                    }else if(b==3)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "three", 100).show();
                    }else if(b==4)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "four", 100).show();
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    b=m[2];
                    if(b==1)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "one", 100).show();
                    }else if(b==2)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "two", 100).show();
                    }else if(b==3)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "three", 100).show();
                    }else if(b==4)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "four", 100).show();
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    b=m[3];
                    if(b==1)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "one", 100).show();
                    }else if(b==2)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "two", 100).show();
                    }else if(b==3)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "three", 100).show();
                    }else if(b==4)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "four", 100).show();
                    }
                    break;              
                default:
                    if(t<=3)
                    {
                        t=3;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    });
    previous.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            t--;
            if(t>=0)
            {
                switch (t) {
                case 1:
                    b=m[0];
                    if(b==1)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "one", 100).show();
                    }else if(b==2)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "two", 100).show();
                    }else if(b==3)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "three", 100).show();
                    }else if(b==4)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "four", 100).show();
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    b=m[1];
                    if(b==1)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "one", 100).show();
                    }else if(b==2)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "two", 100).show();
                    }else if(b==3)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "three", 100).show();
                    }else if(b==4)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "four", 100).show();
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    b=m[2];
                    if(b==1)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "one", 100).show();
                    }else if(b==2)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "two", 100).show();
                    }else if(b==3)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "three", 100).show();
                    }else if(b==4)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "four", 100).show();
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    b=m[3];
                    if(b==1)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "one", 100).show();
                    }else if(b==2)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "two", 100).show();
                    }else if(b==3)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "three", 100).show();
                    }else if(b==4)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "four", 100).show();
                    }
                    break;              

                default:
                    if(t<=0)
                    {
                        t=1;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    });
}
```

> Logcat here

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1522): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    E/AndroidRuntime(1522): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5index=-1
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue?

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=-1

Comment: Are the checkboxes checked by default?

Comment: only unchecked by default ! when checked flag should be increase and unchecked flag decrease at the same in the array index.

Comment: Check my answer below. There should be chk4 instead of chk1 in the listener for chk4

Comment: first chk1 is check to value save index[0],same chk1 is uncheck to value remove  and  another chk2 click to value save to  index[0].

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is here:

```
chk4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(chk1.isChecked())
        {
            flag=4;
            m[increment]=flag;
            increment++;
            count++;        
        }
        else
        {   
            increment--;
            count--;
        }
    }});
```

There should be chk4 instead of chk1 in the if block.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are incrementing "m" out of its bounds in the last block?

```
chk4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(chk1.isChecked())
    {
        flag=4;
        m[increment]=flag;
        increment++;
        count++;        
    }
    else
    {   
        increment--;
        count--;
    }
}});
```